# Scrolling a Div with JQuery without adjusting position

Tags: jquery, scroll

Hello I have a div that I would like to scroll up and down with controls at the top and bottom. I can do this with JQuery by adjusting the position, but that arses up the mouse wheel scroll by moving the entire div. Is there a way to do it by actually scrolling the div.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin

Here is [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more or less what you're asking for.

Very basic implementation but you should be able to get the jist from it.

http://jsfiddle.net/pc4sM/1/